# Firebase offline mode store image

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I was trying to Store data offline by using firebase database reference. I read documentation and it say one line code will store everything.

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

But this line only store text. It's not storing image offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isPersistenceEnabled is only storing your text content. if you want to save image you need to use core data. Core data is little bit hard to save large file. i would recommend to use NSfileManager to Store your image.

Hope it will help .

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send data after you will be connected to WiFi? So you can store your data to CoreData and after you will be connected to Wifi send it to Firebase storage